# Domino Admin: How do I see a list of anonymous http session from the Domino console or in a db?

Tags: ibm-domino

tell http show users - will show us logged in users, but how can we see a list of anonymous users on the site as well as their IP address to know who's browsing the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no live view of anonymous users. But you could activate http logging either to domlog.nsf or the file system. You can get a list of ip's from these log files.